# Specify interface / IP for php imap_open()

Tags: php, imap

I have an application which checks a gmail account via imap using php `imap_open()`.  This works well most of the time but the server has a plethora of IP addresses and it seems the outgoing interface that gets used is a bit of a coin toss.  Sometimes it uses ipv6, other times, ipv4. And for reasons unknown to me, Gmail seems to be finicky about our ipv6 address, despite the fact that it has a valid PTR record.

How can I specify the outgoing IP or interface used by `imap_open()` similarly to [`CURLOPT_INTERFACE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_INTERFACE.html).

Comment: If there is a problem with your IPv6 configuration, this is best solved by fixing it or disabling it if it can't be fixed for now.

Comment: @Brad - It's hard to debug  because, again, I have no way to specify which connection is being used.  If I could even force ipv6, I'd have a way to know if this is a reproducible problem or just gmail being quirky.  All I know for sure is that I occasionally get a rejected connection along with a security notice in my account that provides no details at all about why the alert was raised.

Comment: Nothing in [the `c-client` source code](https://www.washington.edu/imap/) indicates to me that you can select the interface on the client side.

Comment: @billynoah There are ways to specify the connection to be used, but they don't have anything to do with your code.  You can set a hosts file entry to ensure a specific target IP address for the server hostname, and a static route to ensure a consistent network interface is used.

Comment: Thanks @Unimportant - I suspected as much but that's helpful